TypeScript ignores explicit undefined type annotation
When I specify a type of foo|undefined for myConst below, type inspection correctly tells me that myConst has a type of foo|undefined on that line. However, in the next line down, type inspection says that myConst's type is simply foo! Therefore, TypeScript does not require me to access its fields with a ?. operator, and I can trigger a runtime exception. Why is this? Is there any way to make TS respect the explicitly-added undefined type?
type foo = {
  foo?: {
    bar? : {
      text: string
    }
  }
};

const fooArray: foo[] = [{foo: {bar: {text: "hi"}}}];

// type inspection tells me that type is correctly set to "foo|undefined"
const myConst: foo|undefined = fooArray[1];

// myConst type here is just "foo", not "foo|undefined". Where'd the "undefined" go?
// Causes runtime error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'foo') 
const message = myConst.foo?.bar?.text

// never executes
console.log(message);

Playground Link

it can be foo, or it can be undefined.  As is, it becomes undefined, not foo, because JS arrays are zero-indexed.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#noUncheckedIndexedAccess

You're looking at both --noUncheckedIndexedAccess being disabled as well as assignment narrowing. If you're not asking about indexed accessed, perhaps you want something like const myConst: foo | undefined = {foo: {bar: {text: "hi"}}} and not bother with the array stuff, it shows the same narrowing from foo | undefined to foo upon assignment. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a or find a duplicate. If not, what's missing?

The problem that the assignment narrowing is in action as explained by @jcalz. To set the type explicitly use type assertion:
const myConst = fooArray[1] as foo|undefined;

Playground
Another trick is to define your array with possible undefined members:
const fooArray: {[i: number]: foo|undefined} = [{foo: {bar: {text: "hi"}}}];

Playground
You can even use a generic:
type UnsafeArray<T> = {[i: number]: T|undefined};
const fooArray: UnsafeArray<foo> = [{foo: {bar: {text: "hi"}}}];

Playground
All this is implied to work with "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": false

To not ignore possibly undefined values from an array (or any object), add this to your tsconfig.json:
"noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true
Docs reference

I understand that TS ignores these possible undefineds by default, but in this case I specified the undefined type explicitly!
